# How to use React and material-ui with flask backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, python-babel

I am a beginner with react. I was just trying to make a web app with **flask** backend and **react** frontend with **material-ui** but I was facing problems with setting it up.

**What I did**

I downloaded the React Scripts from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html). Then the material-ui from CDN links available [here](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/) and babel from [here](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation). I downloaded and self hosted them all as I am developing for a local network which needs to have offline support.

**My code**

*index.html*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/src/libs/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="/src/js/index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</html>
```

*index.js*

```
import {React} from './src/libs/react.min.js';
import {ReactDOM} from './src/libs/react-dom.min.js';
import * as mui from './src/libs/material-ui.min.js';

ReactDOM.render(<mui.Switch />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Its almost empty because I am just setting up things.

**The error I am facing**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:5:17
    at VH (babel.min.js:1)
    at a (babel.min.js:1)
    at s (babel.min.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.HH.t.forEach.e.src.o.onreadystatechange (babel.min.js:1)
```

Now I don't know how do I get this *require* thing working with a python backend. Is there any other way of solving this problem? It doesn't matter even if all of the code has to be changed as its just the setup and no actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel requires some configuration to work for JSX, and it doesn't support browsers in production. Instead, I'd recommend using [`create-react-app`](https://create-react-app.dev/). All you need to do is create an app and copy your `index.js` into `src`, then you can use the `build` command to get static HTML/JS/CSS files for your Python backend.